# How to create android projects for native applications from terminal?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, project

I would like to speed up my work creating a template for my native applications for Android that only make use of C++ code, this kind of applications have a slightly different manifest and a slightly different folder and file configuration, and i was hoping that i can create a project from the command line with the

```
android create project
```

command.

I'm only interested in creating an android project template for the NDK and for a native activity, nothing else, no java no JNI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create the Android Project as said. You have to create it as it were a pure Java Android project.
2. Create the `jni` folder inside you android project. Create your code and your Makefile. Look at the examples that come with the NDK.
3. Once you have all ( the native code), the manifest for the native activity and the native activity, run `ndk-build` to compile the native part.
4. Then run `ant debug` to build the APK.

Comment: so your answer about this is **no**?

Comment: you said you want a Native activity. This will have to in an APK that will encapsulate the shared library with native code and wich will provide the AndroidManifest.xml file that will tell the system about you native activity and which library should it use. So it is required the base folder structure of and Android App and the build.xml to create the APK to package everything.

Comment: yes, but i also said that i want to save time, this are the steps that i usually take since sdk was out, nothing new ...

Comment: so write a shell script for that